# ESP32 using PubSub, creating an error when implemted inside a library

Tags: library, esp32, mqtt

I wish to combine into a single library Wifi + MQTT, for a multi devices project.

right after boot, getting Wifi - I get an error the moment MQTT server is trying to connect:
`mqttClient.connect(DEVICE_TOPIC, MQTT_USER, MQTT_PASS, MQTTavltopic, 0, true, "offline");`

yields :

```
WiFi connected
IP address: 192.168.3.186
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
Core 1 register dump:
PC      : 0x400d26bd  PS      : 0x00060630  A0      : 0x800d28e8  A1      : 0x3ffb1eb0  
A2      : 0x3ffc116c  A3      : 0x3f4010ef  A4      : 0x3f40108c  A5      : 0x3f4010b7  
A6      : 0x3ffc106c  A7      : 0x00000000  A8      : 0x800d26b6  A9      : 0x3ffb1e90  
A10     : 0x00000000  A11     : 0x3ffc116c  A12     : 0x0000000e  A13     : 0x00000010  
A14     : 0x0000000e  A15     : 0x3ffb1d94  SAR     : 0x0000000c  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x400014fd  LEND    : 0x4000150d  LCOUNT  : 0xfffffffc  

Backtrace: 0x400d26bd:0x3ffb1eb0 0x400d28e5:0x3ffb1ef0 0x400d0fa6:0x3ffb1f20 0x400d103b:0x3ffb1f50 0x400d0e59:0x3ffb1f90 0x400d3651:0x3ffb1fb0 0x40088b7d:0x3ffb1fd0

Rebooting...
```

I'm sharing both `.h` and `.cpp` files.  Library is at its begining - so don't pay attention for irrelevant/ immature parts.

TNX

this is `.h` file:

```
#ifndef myIOT32_h
#define myIOT32_h
#include "Arduino.h"

// #include <ESPmDNS.h>
// #include <WiFiUdp.h>
// #include <ArduinoOTA.h>
#include "time.h"
#include "WiFi.h"
#include "secrets.h"
#include <PubSubClient.h>

class myIOT32
{

#define DEVICE_TOPIC "ESP32_SLEEP"
#define MQTT_PREFIX "myHome"
#define MQTT_GROUP ""
private:
    char MQTTmsgtopic[50];
    char MQTTlogtopic[50];
    char MQTTavltopic[50];
    char MQTTdevtopic[50];
    char MQTTlastctopic[50];
    struct tm _timeinfo;
    time_t _epoch_time;
    bool _wifi_status = false;
    char *wifi_ssid; // = "WIFI_NETWORK_BY_USER";
    char *wifi_pass; // = "WIFI_PASSWORD_BY_USER";
    char *mqtt_server;
    char *user = "";
    char *passw = "";

    WiFiClient espClient;
    PubSubClient mqttClient;

public:
    myIOT32(char *devTopic = "no-name", char *ssid = SSID_ID, char *wifi_p = PASS_WIFI, char *mqtt_broker = MQTT_SERVER1, char *mqttU = MQTT_USER, char *mqttP = MQTT_PASS, int port = 1883);
    void looper();
    void start();
    void mqtt_pubmsg(char *msg);
     bool use_wifi = true;
     void startMQTT();

private:

    void MQTTloop();
    void startNTP(const int gmtOffset_sec, const int daylightOffset_sec, const char *ntpServer);
    bool startWifi();
    void getTime();
    void MQTTcallback(char *topic, byte *payload, unsigned int length);
    void createTopics();
    void connectMQTT();
    void subscribeMQTT();
};
```

## endif

and my `.cpp` file

```
#include "myIOTesp32.h"

myIOT32::myIOT32(char *devTopic, char *ssid, char *wifi_p, char *mqtt_broker, char *mqttU, char *mqttP, int port)
{
  mqtt_server = mqtt_broker;
  user = mqttU;
  passw = mqttP;
  wifi_ssid = ssid;
  wifi_pass = wifi_p;
}
void myIOT32::start()
{
  if(startWifi()){
      getTime();
      startMQTT();
  }
}
void myIOT32::looper()
{
  MQTTloop();
}

void myIOT32::MQTTcallback(char *topic, byte *payload, unsigned int length)
{
  char incoming_msg[150];
  char msg[100];

  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
    incoming_msg[i] = (char)payload[i];
  }
  incoming_msg[length] = 0;
  Serial.println();
}
void myIOT32::createTopics()
{
  sprintf(MQTTmsgtopic, "%s/%s", MQTT_PREFIX, "Messages");
  sprintf(MQTTlogtopic, "%s/%s", MQTT_PREFIX, "log");
  sprintf(MQTTdevtopic, "%s/%s", MQTT_PREFIX, DEVICE_TOPIC);
  sprintf(MQTTavltopic, "%s/%s", MQTTdevtopic, "Avail");
  sprintf(MQTTlastctopic, "%s/%s", MQTTdevtopic, "nexton_command");
}
void myIOT32::connectMQTT()
{
  if (!mqttClient.connected())
  {
    mqttClient.connect(DEVICE_TOPIC, MQTT_USER, MQTT_PASS, MQTTavltopic, 0, true, "offline");
  }
}
void myIOT32::subscribeMQTT()
{
  mqttClient.subscribe(MQTTdevtopic);
  mqttClient.subscribe(MQTTlastctopic);
}
void myIOT32::mqtt_pubmsg(char *msg)
{
  mqttClient.publish(MQTTmsgtopic, msg);
  Serial.print(MQTTmsgtopic);
  Serial.print("/");
  Serial.println(msg);
}
void myIOT32::startMQTT()
{
  mqttClient.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  mqttClient.setCallback(std::bind(&myIOT32::MQTTcallback, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3));
  createTopics();
  connectMQTT();
  subscribeMQTT();
}
void myIOT32::MQTTloop()
{
  static long lastReconnectAttempt = 0;

  if (mqttClient.connected())
  {
    mqttClient.loop();
  }
  else
  {
    long now = millis();
    Serial.println("MQTT Server- NOT connected");
    if (now - lastReconnectAttempt > 5000)
    {
      lastReconnectAttempt = now;
      connectMQTT();
      subscribeMQTT();
    }
  }
}

void myIOT32::startNTP(const int gmtOffset_sec = 2 * 3600, const int daylightOffset_sec = 0, const char *ntpServer = "pool.ntp.org")
{
  configTime(gmtOffset_sec, daylightOffset_sec, ntpServer);
}
bool myIOT32::startWifi()
{
  long beginwifi = millis();
  WiFi.begin(wifi_ssid, wifi_pass);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED && millis() - beginwifi < 30000)
  {
    delay(200);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi connected");
    Serial.print("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    startNTP();
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("NO-WiFi");
    return 0;
  }
}
void myIOT32::getTime()
{
  int a = 0;
  while (a < 3)
  {
    if (getLocalTime(&_timeinfo))
    {
      delay(100);
      time(&_epoch_time);
    }
    a++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myIOT32::myIOT32(char *devTopic, char *ssid, char *wifi_p, char *mqtt_broker, char *mqttU, char *mqttP, int port)
    : mqttClient(espClient)  // <--- this part was missing *****
{
```